# How do I view .nfo files in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm trying to open an .nfo file correctly with the mac terminal (eventually with iTerm2) .

I've tried it already with vim:

```
vim file.nfo
:set encoding=cp437
```

But it has not helped. Maybe there are other tools? May be something in the Brew repository?

Comment: How about `nano file.nfo` ? or is the encoding not working?

Comment: nano didn't helped too. I'm starting to think that there is some strange encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit ambiguous because you don't explicitly state what vim is or is not doing. A .nfo file is just a text file. Vim should be able to correctly handle Unicode encoded text files. If it is a codepage issue then this question on Stack Overflow should explain things:  [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file).